# not even with mail or phpmailer can send mails

Tags: php, email, sendmail, phpmailer

Hy !! i have a big problem, i have an Ubuntu 10.10 with php 5.3.2, I use phpmailer to send mails and the function works like a month ago. But know, it just said, SendEmail with the php mail, or with the phpmailer say's  send!!!

The messages never arrived!! with the 2 functions, i dont know if the php.ini get moves , or somethings else.

All scripts were tested in other servers ( digital ocean ) and they work perfectly.
But know in this server, is not working.

The time I execute @linux: mail.php , its inmediatly, and send my message " SEND MESSAGE".

In Gmail, I already check if where at Spam , but they neever arrived.

No firewall, Ubuntu 10.10, phpmailer lasta version, php 5.3.2

i check with a Python Script with  same configurarion in the same system and works!!!
but with php nothing works!

Please help!!

Comment: perhaps you've been blacklisted

Comment: check your mailqueue ? perhaps the server isn't relaying. perhaps your smtpd has been updated and config overwritten so it'll only relay for local users now not internet facing.  If you are writing into the mail queue ie the smtpd is receiving your mails then you can  try a queue flush and check the error logs / queue logs see why its failing and not sending the mails outbound.  If its not making it to the mail queue then your php is wrong somewhere (or you don't have an smtpd installed)

Answer (score 0):

You need contact the digital ocean support and open a ticket. Same happened to me and I found that they have a block by default for new accounts (to avoid spammers). You need open a ticket ans inform your situation.

When I do this, minutes after they check some information and my mail start to work :)